# Can I declare a function without specifying a type for one of the parameters?

Tags: c, function, syntax

Can a function be defined like this:

```
int foo(int temp1, int temp2 temp3) {
   ...
}
```

Specifically with `temp2` and `temp3`, will that cause errors? If not, what's the overall effect?

Comment: You mean *"defined,"* not *"called"* - why not try it for yourself and see if it generates a compiler error?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this might be valid?

Comment: A question to the community: it's too harsh to answer "LOL" to this kind of questions?

Comment: @akappa: Not in a comment, no.

Comment: What would this declaration mean, i.e. what values could be passed as third argument for this function and how would they be treated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're all **wrong**.. This is *perfectly* valid with:

```
#define temp2 blah) { return 1; } int foo_ (int
int foo(int temp1, int temp2 temp3)
{
        return 0;
}
```

(This is the outcome of me feeling a little humorous first thing in the morning - feel free to downvote if you'd like to ;))

Comment: In this case, the overall effect would be driving the future maintainer insane

Comment: @blueraja - absolutely what i was going for :)

Comment: @oli: decided I *do* like it a little better without the `*` :) +1

Comment: How about `#define temp2 blah) { return 1; } int foo_ (int`?

Answer (score 3):

An error is the overall effect.

Comment: Marked as CW as I shouldn't be getting reputation for such an answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not valid C.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really trying to pass three arguments to a function but you only know the types of two of them at compile time then you can do it using a variable argument list. Suppose you want the third argument to be an `int` or `double` but you have to check `temp1` or `temp2` first to know which it should be:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

int foo(int temp1, int temp2, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int     temp_int;
    double  temp_double;

    va_start(ap, temp2);
    /*
     * Figure out what type you want the third argument to be
     * and use va_arg(ap, int) or va_arg(ap, double) to pull
     * it off the stack.
     */
    va_end(ap);

    /*
     * Get on with what foo() is really all about (including
     * return an int.
     */
}
```

This sort of hack won't protect you against someone saying `foo(1, 2)`, `foo(3, 4, "fish")`, or similar shenanigans but this is C and C assumes that you're grown up and responsible for your own actions.

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot. This will not work because temp3 is not really an argument. The compiler will come up with an error.

Answer (score 0):

if emp2 and temp3 are parameters so, each of them should have its own type, but this will provide a compilation  error

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is not how functions are called but rather how they are declared.  You will need a datatype before each of the formal parameters (int temp1, int temp2, int temp3)